# Finsler length is lower semicontinuous

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

Edit: Corrected the title.

For a smooth (or say, Lipschiz) curve $\gamma: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, define
$$L(\gamma) := \int_a^b f(\gamma’(t), \gamma(t)) dt$$
where $f(\cdot, x)$ is a norm (in the variable $\cdot$) and $f$ is continuous. Prove that L is lower semicontinuous with respect to pointwise convergence, meaning if $\gamma_i$ is a sequence of curves converging to $\gamma$, then
$$\liminf_{i \to \infty} L(\gamma_i) \ge L(\gamma).$$
I could prove this for the ordinary Euclidean length:
$$L(\gamma) = \int_a^b |\gamma’(t)| dt$$
but I can’t seem to deal with the case that the function $f$ depends on the second variable so a similar argument to when this is the ordinary Euclidean length of a curve isn’t working here. In essence, I’ve been having trouble dealing with the fact that something like the following might not hold: $f(v + w, x) \le f(v, x) + f(w, x')$.

Edit: Perhaps I should mention: I got this from exercise 2.4.5 (and exercise 5.1.1) of *A Course in Metric Geometry* by Burago, Burago, and Ivanov. The part that I'm getting is when $f$ does not depend at all on its second variable, but a similar approach I'm using is not working for when $f$ depends on its second variable.

Edit: Fixed some typos.

Edit: changed “seminorm” to “norm” since, as pointed out below, the statement is incorrect for “seminorm.”

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: You might want to check Example 2.4.4 and Excercise 2.4.5 in Burago, Burago, Ivanov's boook "A course on metric geometry" where they state that the Finslerian length is lower semi-continuous if and only if the additivity you are having trouble with holds.

Comment: @SakThis is in fact where I got this question from. I could prove the "only if", but I can't figure out the "if."

Comment: @Sak For the question to make sense, you need some kind of topological structure on the collection of admissible paths. What topological structure do you have (or what definition is it in the book you mentioned)

Comment: @Quoka The topology that the book mentions is pointwise convergence though you can probably assume uniform convergence via Egoroff's theorem. If you have any sort of C^1 convergence, then this inequality is trivial by Fatou's lemma, and in fact would hold even without $f(\cdot, x)$ being a seminorm. Furthermore, the book gives examples where the length fails to be lower semicontinuous, and says that our length is lower semicontinuous if and only if $f(\cdot, x)$ is a seminorm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough to assume $f(\cdot,x)$ is a seminorm - note that a Finsler length structure requires a norm. Consider
\begin{align*}
f(p,x)&=|p_1x_2-p_2x_1+p_3|\\
\gamma(t)&=(0,0,t)&&(0\leq t\leq 1)\\
f(\gamma'(t),\gamma(t))&=1\\
\gamma_i(t)&=(i^{-1}\cos(ti^2),i^{-1}\sin(ti^2),t)\\
\gamma'_i(t)&=(-i\sin(ti^2),i\cos(ti^2),1)\\
f(\gamma'_i(t),\gamma_i(t))&=0
\end{align*}
So $\gamma_i$ converges uniformly to $\gamma,$ but $L(\gamma_i)=0<1=L(\gamma).$

If $f(\cdot,x)$ is a norm, given uniform convergence of $\gamma_i$ you can use an estimate like $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)\|x-y\|\leq\delta\implies f(p,x)\geq (1-\epsilon)f(p,y)$ to locally approximate $f$ by a constant norm. So the argument should be roughly like the Euclidean case.